# Jquery form validation using pre-define class in input type

Tags: jquery, validation

I'm trying to create a function to validate any form using jquery. I have used bootstrap 3 to design my all form and I want to validate each field(s) with mandatory and special validation.

```
<form method="POST>    
  <div class="form-group">
      <label for="customerName" class="control-label">Customer Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="customerName" class="form-control mandatory">
      <p class="help-block text-danger error-mandatory"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
     <label for="mobile" class="control-label">Mobile No</label>
     <input type="text" name="mobile" class="form-control mandatory validate-mobile">
      <p class="help-block text-danger error-mandatory error-mobile"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email" class="control-label">Email</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control mandatory validate-email">
    <p class="help-block text-danger error-mandatory error-email"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="amount" class="control-label">Amount</label>
    <input type="text" name="amount" class="form-control mandatory validate-numeric">
    <p class="help-block text-danger error-mandatory error-numeric"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" onClick="validateForm();" class="btn btn-default">
  </div>
</form>
```

When user click on submit Button form will validate all input type as following:

- if class `mandatory` - validate it empty or not
- if class `mandatory validate-email` - validate empty and validate email format
- if class `mandatory validate-mobile` - validate empty and numeric with 10 digit only
- if class `mandatory validate-numeric` - validate empty and accept numeric only

And Error Message show in

tag class with:

```
'error-mandatory' , 'error-email', 'error-numeric', 'error-mobile'
```

respectively.
I want to create a JS file so I can call this function in any form on submit button. How to I build this any solution, example highly appreciated.

Comment: Using a library like http://happyjs.com/ might be easier than writing the whole thing. Why re-invent the wheel, right?

Comment: Please do **NOT** use the [tag:jquery-validate] tag when the question has nothing to do with the jQuery Validate plugin.  I thought you were asking about this plugin and wasted a lot of time writing an answer until I realized you wanted to write your validation from scratch.

Comment: We are also not a code-writing service.  You are expected to make an honest attempt at writing this code yourself and come here with specific questions if/when you get stuck.  Not dump a list of specifications and expect us to write a tutorial for you.  You might be best looking at the jQuery Validate plugin.... it's very popular and there is lots of support for it here.